# Not able to pull logs from Android using adb pull command

Tags: android, shell, logging

I have some questions about logs in Android.

1. First I want to know where the logs are stored in Android system, directory name.
2. I found from Internet that following logs files are there

> adb pull /data/log c:\folder •  adb pull /data/anr/ C:\folder            •  adb
>   pull /data/dontpanic/ C:\folder
>    •  adb pull /data/kernelpanics/
>   C:\folder  •  adb pull /data/tombstones        •  adb pull
>   /sdcard/bugreports. c:\folder

But when I moved inside adb shell? Data >
I was not able to find any one of that.So not able to pull files from there.

How to view and pull them to my system.

3. Can I pull files from Log driver /dev/log/* usign push command.